# Wavefront meaning

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

A [wavefront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront) is usually defined as the locus of points in which an electromagnetic wave has the same phase.

But, what do we mean with "phase"? Is it a phase in time, or in space, or both? According to wikipedia, it seems to me that it is only a phase in time, but if the wave is in a form like sin(2πf × t - k × x + a), how is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wavefronts are defined during snapshots in time.

Take a three dimensional “photograph” of a wave at one instant of time.
Join points on the wave which are in phase with one another, eg “crests”, and you then have a wavefront.

Take another “photograph” of the wave a little later in time.
Join the points which have the same phase as that in the previous “photograph” to get the new position of the wavefront.

The direction of motion of the wavefront is at right angles to the wavefront.

Comment: Thank you, now it is all clear! Unfortunately I had never found a definition which says that a wavefront is defined during a snapshot. Now it is clear!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we write our wave as:

$$ y(t,x) = \sin(\omega t - k x + \phi) $$

Then the *phase* is the bit inside the brackets i.e.

$$ y(t,x) = \sin(\theta) $$

where the phase $\theta$ is:

$$ \theta = \omega t - k x + \phi $$

So constant phase means a constant value of $\theta$ and that means a constant value of $\omega t - k x + \phi$. So a wavefront is defined by:

$$ \omega t - k x + \phi = A $$

For some constant $A$.

Suppose we rearrange this to:

$$ x = \frac{\omega}{k}t + (\frac{\phi}{k} - A) $$

This gives us the relationship between $x$ and $t$ for our wavefront that has the constant phase $A$. Now we can differentiate it to get the velocity of the wavefront:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\omega}{k} = \frac{2\pi f}{2\pi/\lambda} = f\lambda $$

and this gives us the standard equation $v = f\lambda$ for the velocity of the wave.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what if the wave function does not depend on x (so it is only a sinusoidal function of time)?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo Any propagating wave always depends on both distance and time.

Comment: So a definition of wavefront for a stationary wave does not exist, correct?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo do you mean a [standing wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave)? If so then the function $y(t,x)$ for a standing wave is still a function of both $t$ and $x$. However the only points of constant phase are the nodes so we don't have wavefronts in the sense a travelling wave has wavefronts.

Comment: Perfect, thany you!